# Flatten Writes with Play Json

Tags: scala, play-json

Due to the 22 field limit I had to split a large case class into smaller classes.  How can I flatten the `Writes` of this large class?

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class B(x: Option[Int], y: Option[Int])

object B {
  implicit val format: (Reads[B], Writes[B]) => Format[B] = Format[B]
}

case class C(z: Option[Int], w: Option[Int])

object C {
  implicit val format: (Reads[C], Writes[C]) => Format[C] = Format[C]
}

case class A(b: B, c: C)

object A {
  implicit val reads: Reads[A] =
    (Reads.of[B] and Reads.of[C]) (A.apply _)

  implicit val writes: Writes[A] = ???
  /*
  val a = A(B(1, 2), C(3, 4)

  Json.toJson(a) should be

  {
    "x": 1
    "y": 2
    "z": 3
    "w": 4
  }
   */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short story, you can do this :

```
implicit val writes: Writes[A] = JsPath.write[B].and(JsPath.write[C]) (unlift(A.unapply _))
```

Long story: Why are you able to use `and` method ?

`and` is available for any class that implements the typeclass `FunctionalCanBuild`. What I noticed so far is that there is no such typeclass for `Writes`, however there is one for `OWrites`.

Using `JsPath.write[B]` yields a `OWrites` value, therefore `and` method is available. On the other hand, using `Writes.of[]` yields a `Writes`, and `OWrites.of[]` yields a `Writes[]`. In the end, any method to get a `OWrites[]` will allow you to use the key word and.

Also, looking further into the code, any instance of `Applicative` typeclass is translatable to an instance of `FunctionalCanBuild`. This typeclass is implemented for any `Reads` hence the available `and` method on the `Readers.`

Comment: what would be the Reads equivalent of this?